Detect all places to fix "Cannot compare left expression" after upgrading to Hibernate 6
After upgrading to Spring Boot 3.3 and Hibernate 6.5.2.Final I face the following runtime issue occurring in  different places in the application:
Cannot compare left expression of type '...' with right expression of type '...'

I understand the source of the problem (Hibernate 6.x expects the same data type on join statements) and I know how to fix it but I wondered if there is a way to detect all the places in the source code which need to be fixed. I tried to find a recipe provided by OpenRewrite but there is no one if I'm not mistaken.

There's indeed no such recipe yet, but you're welcome to log an issue: https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-hibernate
I'll try to guide you through what such a recipe would entail if I have more details.
